Button's font weight changes on hover with transition
When I hover over a button all other buttons' font weight flickers for a small amount of time.
Setting the font size and boldness, removing the :active pseudo selector, and using :after doesn't fix it as well. Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/EdenTheCoder/pen/gOyJjBB


body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #131313;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 5px 5px;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 242);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ffffff00;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 242);
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.buttons:hover {
  transform: scale(0.95);
  transition: 200ms;
  color: rgb(255, 134, 249);
  border-color: rgb(75, 40, 202);
}

.buttons:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: 100ms;
  color: rgb(255, 78, 175);
  border-color: rgb(75, 40, 202);
}
<button class="buttons">button</button>
<button class="buttons">button</button>
<button class="buttons">button</button>




Please make your code into a runnable snippet and test that it shows the problem. Also I am not understanding the https://codepen… plonked in amongst the CSS.

Your buttons are shrinking on hover, so if the cursor is near the border the effects start fighting. (hover ends because the button shrank far enough that the mouse is no longer hovering, so the button grows, which puts the mouse cursor over it again, triggering hover, so the button shrinks, repeat)

That is due to the scaling property applied.

@DanielBeck I agree initially, but the problem still happens if you add a long transition-delay and move the cursor to the middle before transition started, which shouldn't happen anymore if that is the reason, right?

I don't see any flicker when the cursor is far from the edge.

@DanielBeck For me not on FF but on Chrome and Edge the font weight does flickers as soon as the mouse enters even with transition-delay: 10000ms. Doesn't seem to be the problem of <button>'s UA style as it reproduces on <div> as well.

This seems to be caused by the font's sub-pixel rendering result not being retained on elements after a positioned element when an animation is triggered. (I'm guessing this because removing position:relative also solves the problem.) I can only reproduce on Windows Chrome and Edge, so I'm not sure if this is a bug on Blink or not.
One fix is by adding a higher z-index on the hovered element (or removing position:relative as stated above if not needed).


body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #131313;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 5px 5px;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 242);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ffffff00;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 242);
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.buttons:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(0.95);
  transition: 200ms;
  color: rgb(255, 134, 249);
  border-color: rgb(75, 40, 202);
}

.buttons:active {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: 100ms;
  color: rgb(255, 78, 175);
  border-color: rgb(75, 40, 202);
}
<button class="buttons">button</button>
<button class="buttons">button</button>
<button class="buttons">button</button>



